# Linux zero config file sync or share?

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, file-synchronization, cloud-storage

One or two months ago I read an article about an (perhaps) old Linux utility which did backup/sync/folder sharing completely different compared to normal rsync and similar utils.

All I remember were something about being "zero configuration". The article might not have used the term "zero configuration", but the means was the same.

Can anyone based on this wage description come up with some potential candidates of what it could be?